# vuejs dynamically adding class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Using vuejs 3. In the vuejs app, I have:

```js
data(){
    return{
        return_prohibited:false
    }
}
```

`return_prohibited` turns to `true` when the server returns an error message from a fetch request:

```js
fetch(myUrl,this.myInit)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
          if (data.message) {
              this.credits = []
              this.debits = []
              return_prohibited = true
         } // cut for brievity
```

**Html file:**

```
<button @click="previousMonth" id="bouton_mois_prec" :class="{interdit:return_prohibited}" >précédent</button>
```

I was expecting that the css class `interdit` would be added to the button each time that `return_probibited` is true, as per [these explanations](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax). But nothing happens.

Comment: What changes `return_prohibited`?

Comment: I have updated the question with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append `this.` in front of `return_prohibited` - otherwise you will get errors in the console.